# Locking the campaign Pages of website -- shopify

Tags: shopify-app

I am trying to create a shopify app which is kind of similar to Locksmith shopify app. My intention is to lock the campaign or products depending on the code generated by the shopify app.

I am still confused how to do it and which shopify API endpoint to use.

Thanks in advance.

I am reading the shopify api documentation and I am expecting to get a direction to implement such an appp.